# Allow < and > to be entered into text fields to submit in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, forms, textfield

For some weird reason when I enter such characters in text fields and press submit button I getting blank page loaded and **I don't see any errors appear**.

Comment: Markups are interpreted as dangerous input, so they will be rejected with showing nothing to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `requestValidationMode` in your **`web.config`** file.

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Also you can set `ValidateRequest` to **`false`** in your page directive.

```
<%@ Page ... ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

Comment: The second solution is more good since I want it disabled for admin page only. Thank you.

Comment: Huh, the second method does not work O_o  I have this `<%@ Page Language = "C#" ValidateRequest = "false" CodeFile="include/functions.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>` on admin page but still blank page when I try to add some html tags into input.

Comment: First one is fine, but that way I need to protect other fields. That's not a problem, I can live with that. Just saying that second method does not work.

Comment: Now I got it... Second method works only when combined with first one. It's not `Also I can set`, it's `After this you can set`

Comment: Oh yeah, You need both to make them work correctly, I couldn't recall it as it has been a year or so I worked on asp.net.